# Check if both fields are entered and minimum characters using jQuery validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

here's my code below. I'm able to test if either one of the 2 fields are entered. What I want now is to limit the user to enter only 1 field but not both and how do I get user to enter at least 3 characters? I tried adding to the rules but it's not working. Am I able to put if/else statement under rules? Thanks. Need help badly.

```
reg: function() {
            reg_validator = $('.form_validation_reg').validate({
                onkeyup: false,
                errorClass: 'error',
                validClass: 'valid',
                highlight: function(element) {
                    $(element).closest('div').addClass("f_error");
                },
                unhighlight: function(element) {
                    $(element).closest('div').removeClass("f_error");
                },
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    $(element).closest('div').append(error);
                },
                rules: {     
                        campaign_name: {
                                require_from_group: [1, '.span8']
                        },
                        campaign_name2: {
                                require_from_group: [1, '.span8']
                        }  
                },
                invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
                    $.sticky("There are some errors. Please correct them and submit again.", {autoclose : 5000, position: "top-right", type: "st-error" });
                }
            })
        }
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP....?

Comment: where is the rule require_from_group

Comment: can you edit [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fn2pd/1/) to recreate your problem

Comment: sorry, this has nothing to do with php.. just jquery... anyway, fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/fn2pd/5/

Comment: @ArunPJohny, `require_from_group` is part of the jQuery Validate plugin.  It's in the `additional-methods.js` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the jQuery Validation plugin is for validation of entered data, and nothing about validation would *prevent* the user from entering data into an empty field, you can enable/disable the opposite field on blur.  Assuming the `span8` class is only used on these two fields.

```
$('.span8').on('blur', function () {            
    if ($(this).val() != '') {                  
        $('.span8').not(this).prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('.span8').not(this).removeProp('disabled');
    }
});
```

**Quote OP**:

> *"how do I get user to enter at least 3 characters?"*

Use the `minlength` rule...

```
rules: {
    campaign_name: {
        require_from_group: [1, '.span8'],
        minlength: 3
    },
    campaign_name2: {
        require_from_group: [1, '.span8'],
        minlength: 3
    }
}
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/htd23/**

---

If you don't want to disable fields on blur and just prefer to use validation, here is a custom validation method you can use...

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('notBoth', function (value, element, param) {
    return ((value != '') && ($(param[0]).val() == '') || (value == '') && ($(param[0]).val() != ''));
}, "Please do not fill out both fields");
```

to declare the custom method...

```
rules: {
    campaign_name: {
        require_from_group: [1, '.span8'],
        minlength: 3,
        notBoth: ['input[name="campaign_name2"]'] // parameter is the other field
    },
    campaign_name2: {
        require_from_group: [1, '.span8'],
        minlength: 3,
        notBoth: ['input[name="campaign_name"]'] // parameter is the other field
    }
}
```

**Alternate DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/EqF5F/**

---

**Notes**:

- When you use `onkeyup: false`, you will not see the `minlength` rule work until blur or submit.
- I removed all the callback methods to focus the demo on the specific issues.
- You do not need to declare `validClass` and `errorClass` when you've only set them to their default values.

Comment: You're my life saver, it works! Finally, I've got what I wanted, thank you so much ;)